# Retrieving values from mvc View to Controller

Tags: model-view-controller, request.form

I have a Captured Photo image that needs to be sent to the Controller for processing.
All images below are populated with the same picture, in a test to see what's passed back on form-submit

```
<img id="facePic" class="main-info-img" src="../../assets/img/scan-face.png">
<img alt="Hidden Image" name="hiddenFace" id="hiddenFace" />
<input type="hidden" alt="Hidden Image" name="hiddenImage" id="hiddenImage" />
```

Inside the controller, the basic Request.Form text fields' values are available,
for instance  string frmDept = Request.Form["DepartmentId"];  contains "1"

but NO Request.Form image data is available

```
string frmVar = Request.Form["facePic"];                 //(empty)
string frmFace = Request.Form["hiddenImage"];            //(empty)
```

If there's any other way to get the image data passed, your suggestions would be appreciated.

Amongst others, I have tried to retrieve the image from the Model parameter, but that's not working